# Different middleware for resource route

Tags: laravel

I have a resource controller and a route:

```
Route::resource('/path', Controller::class)
```

For each method of this controller I need to use different middleware. Can I do it inside route file, not in __construct() method?

I need something like that

```
Route::resource('/path', Controller::class)->middleware(['index' => 'guest', 'create' => 'auth'])
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is not possible with a single `resource` route definition method. Maybe you can create a suggestion about this in [laravel/ideas](https://github.com/laravel/ideas)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define each routes individually.

```
Route::resource('/path', Controller::class);
```

Is similar to :

```
Route::get('/path', [Controller::class, 'index'])->name('path.index');
Route::get('/path/create', [Controller::class, 'create'])->name('path.create');
Route::post('/path', [Controller::class, 'store'])->name('path.store');
Route::get('/path/{path}', [Controller::class, 'show'])->name('path.show');
Route::get('/path/{path}/edit', [Controller::class, 'edit'])->name('path.edit');
Route::put('/path/{path}', [Controller::class, 'update'])->name('path.update');
Route::delete('/path/{path}', [Controller::class, 'destroy'])->name('path.destroy');
```

With second route definition, you can add your middlewares.
So :

```
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/path', [Controller::class, 'index'])->name('path.index');
    Route::get('/path/{path}', [Controller::class, 'show'])->name('path.show');
});
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/path/create', [Controller::class, 'create'])->name('path.create');
    Route::post('/path', [Controller::class, 'store'])->name('path.store');
    Route::get('/path/{path}/edit', [Controller::class, 'edit'])->name('path.edit');
    Route::put('/path/{path}', [Controller::class, 'update'])->name('path.update');
    Route::delete('/path/{path}', [Controller::class, 'destroy'])->name('path.destroy');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#controller-middleware)

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('log')->only('index');
        $this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
    }
}
```